# Can I define two different call functions in Keras, one for a foward map and another for an inverse map

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to implement an INN (invertible neural network) with the structure as described in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.04730.pdf).

I was wondering if it is possible to create a block (as proposed in the paper) as a custom keras layer with two different call functions.

The basic structur would look as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as layers

class INNBlock(tf.keras.Model):
#inheriting from model instead of keras.layers.Layer, because I want manage the 
#underlying layer as well
    def __init__(self, size):
        super(INNBlock, self).__init__(name='innblock')
        #define layers
        self.denseL1 = layers.Dense(size,activation='relu')

    def call(self, inputs):
        #define the relationship between the layers for a foward call
        out = self.denseL1(inputs)
        return out

    def inverse_call(self, inputs):
        #define inverse relationship between the layer
        out = -self.denseL1(inputs) #use the same weights as the foward call
        return out

class INN(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,kenel_size,input_dim,min_clip,max_clip):
        super(INN, self).__init__()
        self.block_1 = INNBlock(size)
        self.block_2 = INNBlock(size)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.block_1(inputs)
        x = self.block_2.inverse_call(y)
        x = self.block_1.inverse_call(x)
        return (y,x)
```

Solutions I already thought of (but don't particulary like):

- Creating new layers for the inverse call and give them the same weights as the layers in the forward call.
- Adding another dimension to inputs and have a variable in there, that determines whether or not the inverse call or the foward call is to be executed (but I don't know if this would even be allowed by keras)

I hope someone knows, if there is a way to implement this. 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you try your code? It seems ok.

Comment: It seems like it does ._. I though the operations wouldn't be exposed to keras, if I don't call them in the defined way. But I just tried to map from x -> x (the network has to learn to do nothing and that worked very well)

Do you know, if the update on the weights will happen twice now, since they are in two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You can try it and it will run normally.

The `call` method is the standard method for when you simply do `model_instance(input_tensor)` or `layer_instance(input_tensor)`.

But there is nothing wrong if you define another method and use that method inside the model's call method. What will happen is just:

- If you use `the_block(input_tensor)`, it will use `the_block.call(input_tensor)`.
- If you use `the_block.inverse_call(input_tensor)` somewhere outside a layer/model, it will fail to build a Keras model (nothing can be outside a layer)
- If you use `the_block.inverse_call(input_tensor)` inside a layer/model (that's what you're doing), it is exactly the same as just writing the operations directly. You just wrapped it inside another function.

For Keras/Tensorflow, there will be nothing special about `inverse_call`. You can use it anywhere you could use any other keras/tensorflow function.

---

**Will the gradients be updated twice?**

Not exactly twice, but the operation will certainly be counted in. When the system calculates the gradient of the loss with relation to the weights, if the loss was built with `inverse_call` in the way, then it will participate in the gradient calculation.

But the update will be once per batch, as usual.